# android activity call and return result

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activity A , B and C
Flow is:
**Activity A calls B , B Call C. (A -> B -> C )** 
Now I am in Activity C and want to return some result to Activity A without involving B.
Scenario is Activity B should be call only by A ( if user press back button from C , B will not be call and activity A will comes in front).
Any one let me know how to deal with this situation.

Update :

I am calling activity B from A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

in same way I am calling C from B.

In A i am over riding `onActivityResult` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- start ActivityB as `StartActivityForResult` from ActivityA.
- In onCreate() method start ActivityC as `StartActivityForResult` from ActivityB. `Don't finish ActivityB`.
- From ActivityC when work done `set the result`.
- In ActivityB when you get the result in the `OnActivityResult()` set the result to ActivityA and finish ActivityB.
- From ActivityC override `onBackPressed()` and set the result null and finish the ActivityC

Answer (score 1):

call finish() after startActivity call to C in Activity B

Comment: but how to return result to activity A.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple way u  do

in Acvtivity C

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A.class);
i.putExtra("id", id);
startActivity();
```

On backBtn Event

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
       Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A.class);
       i.putExtra("id", id);
       startActivity();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call `Activity C from B by startActivityForResult()` and then in `Activity B override onActivityResult() and put finish()`;  Also from `Activity A start Activity B by startActivityForResult()` This will direct to Activity A without reCreated it.